# ERROR - ListenerManager Couldn't initialize the httpstransport listener - WSO2

Tags: java, https, wso2, wso2-api-manager

I started fresh copy of the WSO2 API Manager 1.8 and get below error for no reason.

```
ERROR - ListenerManager Couldn't initialize the httpstransport listener
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check the system hostname by running following command

```
$ hostname
```

try to ping to the output for that hostname.

```
$ ping <output of the hostname command>
```

If that gives an error check the `/etc/hosts` file. At least it should have a host entry to 127.0.0.1

```
127.0.0.1 <hostname>
or 
<local ip> <hostname>
```

Comment: Since I'm doing a cloud deployment having a local IP didn't make a much of a difference. Anyway thanks for the answer +1.

Answer (score 1):

Type

```
root@S-06:hostname
S-06
```

Type get your IP

```
root@S-06:ifconfig
```

Add it to `vim /etc/hosts` as a record.

```
192.168.4.123   S-06
```

Comment: There is no `v` flag for hostname